# How to deep copy an object to another class object with same fields?

Tags: java, deep-copy

I have two java classes as follows

```
public class A implements Serializable {

    private String name;
    private List<String> nameList;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public List<String> getNameList() {
        return nameList;
    }
    public void setNameList(List<String> nameList) {
        this.nameList = nameList;
    }   
}

public class B implements Serializable {

    private String name;
    private List<String> nameList;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public List<String> getNameList() {
        return nameList;
    }
    public void setNameList(List<String> nameList) {
        this.nameList = nameList;
    }   
}
```

Now I have an object of class A, Aobj, with both the fields initialized. I am using BeanUtils.copyProperties(Bobj, Aobj), but only the `name` field value is copied into the Bobj however Bobj.nameList is null. Is there a way to deep copy a object so that it copies all the fields including Collections like List, Map etc.

I somewhere heard about Dozer, not sure if that is meant for this purpose.

Comment: Why don't you copy manually? (for example with copy const.)

Comment: Yes, Dozer is meant for exactly this kind of use case. By default, it maps fields with identical property names between two objects of different class types. You can configure which fields are mapped, how they are mapped, and how their values are read and set, if necessary. In your particular case, the default mapping would work just fine.

Comment: @Ahmet AY Yes, I am currently doing it manually. The thing is my actual use case deals with object that has many fields not just 2 and manually doing so for different looked too cumbersome.

Comment: @MarkusFischer Sure, I will look into how to use Dozer!

Comment: Sounds like an [XYProblem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why do you have two separate classes with the **exact same** attributes and methods ? Why do you need to clone them ?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit strange that you have 2 different classes that are absolutely identical. But regardless, in order to deep copy one to another just write a 2 static methods in some Util class. One method will take class A and return class B and another will take B and return class A. Do your deep copying by yourself. Also, you can create class C that is the same as your classes A and B and then make your classes A and B just empty classes each extending C. It would give you the same structure, but would make your copying logic easier as you can just work with both A and B as instances of C.